# How to create spacing of points per decade for logarithmic plot

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, logarithm

**Intro**

I have some range of frequencies that goes from `freq_start_hz = X` to `freq_stop_hz = Y`.

I am trying to logarithmically (base 10) space out samples between the range `[freq_start_hz, freq_stop_hz]`, based on a number of samples per [decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_(log_scale)) (`num_samp_per_decade`), inclusive of the endpoint.

I noticed `numpy` has a method `logspace` ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html)) which enables you to create logarithmic divisions of some range `base ** start` to `base ** stop` based on a total number of samples, `num`.

Can you help me create Python code that will create even logarithmic spacing per decade?

**Example**

`freq_start_hz = 10`, `freq_stop_hz = 100`, `num_samp_per_decade = 5`

This is easy, since it's just one decade.  So one could create it using the following:

```
import numpy as np
from math import log10


freq_start_hz = 10
freq_stop_hz = 100
num_samp_per_decade = 5

freq_list = np.logspace(
    start=log10(freq_start_hz), 
    stop=log10(freq_stop_hz), 
    num=num_samp_per_decade, 
    endpoint=False,
    base=10,
)
freq_list = np.append(freq_list, freq_stop_hz)  # Appending end
print(freq_list.tolist())
```

Output is `[10.0, 17.78279410038923, 31.622776601683793, 56.23413251903491, 100.0]`

Note: this worked nicely because I designed it this way.  If `freq_start_hz = 8`, this method no longer works since it now spans multiple decades.

**Conclusion**

I am hoping somewhere out there, there's a premade method in `math`, `numpy`, another `scipy` library, or some other library that my internet searching hasn't turned up.

Comment: If the range is two decades and `num_samp_per_decade = 5` , how many total points are there? If the range is two and one-half decades?

Comment: If the range is one decade, I would want `num_samp_per_decade + 1`.  If the range is 2.5 decades, I would want the last half decade to just have another logspace done (as if full decade), and then truncate out extra values, and then append the final decade value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the number of points based on the number of decades in the range.

```
from math import log10
import numpy as np

start = 10
end = 1500
samples_per_decade = 5

ndecades = log10(end) - log10(start)
npoints = int(ndecades) * samples_per_decade
#a = np.linspace(log10(start), log10(end), num = npoints)
#points = np.power(10, a)
points = np.logspace(log10(start), log10(end), num=npoints, endpoint=True, base=10)
print(points)
```